# Taylor approximation in R

Tags: r

Is there a function/package in **R** which takes a function f and a parameter k, and then returns a Taylor approximation of f of degree k?

Comment: Do you mean which takes some arbitrary R-function (numeric function of one argument, assumed continuousm say) as input and returns a numerically-approximated function as output? Or returns a numerically approximated *value* as output? Or do you mean something that takes a simple-ish expression as input and returns an expression as output, somewhat akin to the `D` function? Or something else?

Comment: I am just looking for a numerical approximation.

Comment: Note that this seems more of a stackoverflow question ("does R do this?") than a stats.SE question.

Comment: That is true. I might want to migrate it if no answer comes up within a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a thing, but with a few assumptions about the supplied function, it would be fairly easy to write one that would do numeric first or second derivatives. However, you must beware numeric derivatives, especially as the order of the Taylor expansion goes up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`Ryacas`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/)  to work with the [yacas](http://yacas.sourceforge.net/homepage.html) computer algebra system (which you will need to install as well)

Using an example from the vignette

```
 library(Ryacas)
 # run   yacasInstall() if prompted to install yacas
 #
 yacas("texp := Taylor(x,0,3) Exp(x)")
 ## expression(x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + 1)
 # or
```

Now, if you want to turn that into a function that you can give values of `x`

```
myTaylor <- function(f, k, var,...){
  .call <- sprintf('texp := Taylor( %s, 0, %s) %s', var,k,f)
  result <- yacas(.call)
  foo <- function(..., print = FALSE){
    if(print){print(result)}
    Eval(result, list(...))}
  return(foo)
}
# create the function
foo <- myTaylor('Exp(x)', 3, 'x')
foo(x=1:5)
## [1]  2.666667  6.333333 13.000000 23.666667 39.333333
foo(x=1:5, print = TRUE)
## expression(x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + 1)
## [1]  2.666667  6.333333 13.000000 23.666667 39.333333
```

Answer (score 5):

Compare the above symbolic solution with a numerical Taylor approximation:

```
library(pracma)

p <- taylor(f = exp, x0 = 0, n = 4)             # Numerical coefficients 
# 0.1666667 0.5000000 1.0000000 1.0000000       # x^3/6 + x^2/2 + x + 1

polyval(p, 1:5)                                 # Evaluate the polynomial
# 2.66667  6.33333 13.00000 23.66667 39.33334   # exp(x) at x = 1:5
```

Comment: Be interesting to see at what level of precision this differs from the yacas result :-).

Comment: I get the following: `Rgames> p <- taylor(f = exp, x0 = 0, n = 4)
Rgames> p
[1] 0.04166657 0.16666673 0.50000000 1.00000000 1.00000000
`  , which is what is expected for `taylor(exp,1,4)` .  I think you meant to type `n=3` in your formula.

Answer (score 1):

As a followup, consider:

```
 foo <- myTaylor('Exp(x)', 3, 'x')
sprintf('%2.15f',foo(x=1:5))
[1] "2.666666666666667"  "6.333333333333333"  "13.000000000000000"
[4] "23.666666666666664" "39.333333333333329"

p <- taylor(f = exp, x0 = 0, n = 3)
sprintf('%2.15f',polyval(p,1:5))
[1] "2.666666721845557"  "6.333333789579300"  "13.000001556539996"
[4] "23.666670376066413" "39.333340601497312"
```

Which of these is more accurate I'll leave up to the reader :-)

Comment: You should also consider that Ryacas is *not* a very powerful CAS, i.e. will not return the Taylor series for too many functions. It is clear that numerical derivatives are not as accurate as theoretical ones (who said differently?), but it is a nice and practical alternative.

Comment: @HansWerner  I did not mean in any way to denigrate your answer, so I apologize for my poor wording.

Comment: No need to apologize. Just wanted to make I sure I didn't mean numerical derivatives can be as exact as analytical ones. BTW1: If looking for a CAS in R I would suggest `SymPy`, not `Ryacas`. BTW2: the discussion encouraged me to allow higher orders in the `taylor` function -- comes out relatively well even for orders up to 8 or 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for Taylor approximation in a background of error propagation, you might try the "propagate" function of my `qpcR` package, which evaluates symbolic gradient vectors together with the covariance matrix in the form of `g * V * t(g)` (the famous matrix notation for error propagation), which is equivalent to the first-order Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 1):

The below function returns the function obtained by using the Taylor series approximation of n-th order of function f at the point a.

```
taylor <- function(f, n, a) {

    ith_derivative <- as.expression(body(f))
    f_temp <- function(x) x
    series <- as.character(f(a))
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
        ith_derivative <- body(f_temp) <- D(ith_derivative, "x")
        series <- paste0(series, "+", f_temp(a) / factorial(i), "*(x - ", a, ")^", i)
    }
    f_output <- function(x) x
    body(f_output) <- parse(text = series)
    f_output

}

taylor(f = function(x) sin(x), n = 3, a = 0)
```