# How to combine expressions in R

Tags: r

I want to combine expressions by add them together, or by division (code below), and I'm getting an error:

> non-numeric argument to binary operator

How to get the combination?

```
a=0
fun2 = expression(sin(x))
fun4 = expression(sin(pi/4))
N=1
while(N<3){
  fun1 = fun2
  fun2 = D(fun1,"x")
  fun3 = expression(fun2/(prod(1:N)*(x-1)^N))
  fun4 = expression(fun4+fun3)
  N=N+1
}
```

Comment: You could try `fun3 <- expression(eval(fun2)/(prod(1:N)*(x-1)^N))` and `fun4 <- expression(eval(fun4)+eval(fun3))`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with these expressions anyway? I'm not sure I understand to goal here.

Comment: trying to get a Taylor's formula of a function，then draw the result by setting x value

Comment: To obtain an analytic form of a Taylor expansion of a given function up to specific order near a specific point,  you'll probably need `yacas` and `Ryacas`, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765103/taylor-approximation-in-r). Or you might use the `rSymPy` package, but in that case it may be easier to use `Python` instead of `R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive implementation to build a taylor expansion.  The result is of class "call", but you can evaluate it like you would an expression.  It basically just builds an expression tree, adding each additional term in the taylor expansion recursively.

```
taylor <- function(f, a, deg, curr=NULL) {
    if (is.function(f)) f <- body(f)  # use the body of the function for derivatives

    ## Base cases
    if (missing(curr))
        return( as.call(list(`+`, eval(f, list(x=a)), taylor(f, a, deg, 1))) )
    if (curr == deg+1) return ( 0 )

    ## Build each additional term
    return (
        as.call(list(`+`,
                     as.call(list(`/`,
                                  as.call(list(`*`,
                                               eval(D(f, "x"), list(x=a)),
                                               as.call(list(`^`, as.call(list(`-`, quote(x), a)), curr)))),
                                  prod(1:curr))),
                     taylor(D(f, "x"), a, deg, curr=curr+1)))
    )
}
```

You can see the expression this returns

```
## You function, parameters
f <- function(x) sin(x)
a <- 0

(t3 <- taylor(f, a, 3))
# .Primitive("+")(0, .Primitive("+")(.Primitive("/")(.Primitive("*")(1, 
#     .Primitive("^")(.Primitive("-")(x, 0), 1)), 1), .Primitive("+")(.Primitive("/")(.Primitive("*")(0, 
#     .Primitive("^")(.Primitive("-")(x, 0), 2)), 2), .Primitive("+")(.Primitive("/")(.Primitive("*")(-1, 
#     .Primitive("^")(.Primitive("-")(x, 0), 3)), 6), 0))))
```

And, to see if it is working

```
## Look at it
xs <- seq(-4, 4, len=100)
curve(f, -4, 4, type="p", pch=".", cex=4, main="Approximations of sin(x) at x=1",
      ylim=c(-2, 2))

cols <- colorRampPalette(c("orange", "red"))(7)
with(list(x=xs), {
    for (i in 1:7)
        points(xs, eval(taylor(f, a=1, i)), col=cols[i], lty=2, type="l", lwd=2)
})
```

[image]